# Angular Ui-Grid ng-blur event does not fire

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using Angular UI-Grid v3.0.4. I am using columndef cell-template to get the required customization as below (I have ng-blur event and method within celltemplate).

```
   $scope.gridOptions = {
           showColumnFooter: true,
           columnDefs: [
                        {
                            name: "SalesAmount", displayName: "Sales Amount"
                        },
                        {
                            name: "CommissionAmount", displayName: "Commission Amount", enableCellEdit: true, enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
                            cellTemplate: '<input type="text" ng-model="row.entity.pddCommissionAmount" ng-blur="updateEntitys(row.entity)"></input>'
                        }

                       ]
                     };
```

ng-blur event does not fire its execution. Researched and add a custom ngblur directive to see if that helps

```
app.directive('ngBlur', function () {
    return function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.bind('blur', function () {
            scope.$apply(attrs.ngBlur);
        });
    };
});



$scope.updateEntitys = function (row) {
             alert("Update Entitys within ngblur event");
         }
```

This does not seem work either. Greatly appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about ui-grid but I'm fairly sure that the reason to why it doesn't work is that the html in the so called "cellTemplate" is never compiled because it's not actually an *angular template*. I believe you could find a way around it using `$compile`, passing the html to the cellTemplate while saving the object to some variable, but I also think that would be an incredibly convoluted way to do what you want (whatever that is?).

Instead, I think you should have a look at the ui-grid documentation about the edit-feature: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable

I *think* this is what you actually want:

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi) {
  $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
  gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope, function(rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log('edited row id:' + rowEntity.id + ' Column:' + colDef.name + ' newValue:' + newValue + ' oldValue:' + oldValue);
    $scope.$apply();
  });
};
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/GJfBpn0kIkhgrPAPUYSb?p=preview